# Vyper how to convert uint256 to String?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, vyper

I need to convert a uint256 to String in vyper, I notice that theres something similar on Solidity (Taken from [OpenSea's docs](https://docs.opensea.io/docs/metadata-standards)):

```
/**
   * @dev Returns an URI for a given token ID
   */
  function tokenURI(uint256 _tokenId) public view returns (string) {
    return Strings.strConcat(
        baseTokenURI(),
        Strings.uint2str(_tokenId)
    );
  }
```

There's a method called "Strings.uint2str()", is there something equivalent in Vyper?

Comment: The Solidity code is a using an external library named `Strings` and its function `uint2str()` - not a native function... Based on the context specified in the OpenSea docs page, it seems like they use the OpenZeppelin [Strings](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.2.0/contracts/utils/Strings.sol) library that might have had the `uint2str()` function in earlier versions, but now there's the `toString()` function to convert an `uint256` value to a `string`.

Comment: The bad news is that the toString() function is an implementation for Solidity right? not Vyper.

Comment: That's correct, it's in Solidity - not Vyper. My comment was simply aiming to highlight the fact that it's a custom function, not a native one.

Comment: I am not a Vyper expert. But you can use abi encode and decode then uint256 that variable. It should work because everything is byte you know :)

Answer (score 1):

the vyper git repo has an examples folder, one of which is for tokens which contains and [ERC-721 contract implementation](https://github.com/vyperlang/vyper/blob/master/examples/tokens/ERC721.vy) in vyper

```
@view
@external
def tokenURI(tokenId: uint256) -> String[132]:
    return concat(self.baseURL, uint2str(tokenId))
```

in the [vyper docs](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/built-in-functions.html?highlight=uint2str#uint2str)

> uint2str(value: unsigned integer)→ String
> Returns an unsigned integer’s string representation.
>
> value: Unsigned integer to convert.
>
> Returns the string representation of value.